# React native - objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store})

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React Native and I'm getting an error quoted below:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Here's my whole code included in the component file, except styling:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'firebase';

class LoginForm extends Component {

    state = { email: '', password: '', error: '', loading: false };

    onButtonPress(){
        const email = this.state.email;
        const password = this.state.password;

        this.setState({error: '', loading: true});

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
            .catch(() => {
                firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(this.onLoginSuccess.bind(this))
                .catch(this.onLoginFail.bind(this));
            });
    }

    onLoginSuccess(){
        this.setState({email: '', password: '', error: '', loading: false});
    }

    onLoginFail(){
        this.setState({error: 'Nie udalo sie utworzyc konta.', loading: false});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                    <Image 
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={require('../images/loginIcon.png')}
                    />
                </View>
                <View style={styles.formContainer}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Email..."
                        placeholderTextColor='rgba(255,255,255,0.9)'
                        underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                        onChangeText={(email) => this.setState({email: email})}
                        value={this.state.email}
                        autoCorrect={false}
                    />
                    <TextInput
                        style={styles.input}
                        placeholder="Hasło..."
                        placeholderTextColor='rgba(255,255,255,0.9)'
                        underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password: password})}
                        value={this.state.password}
                        secureTextEntry
                    />
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.button}>
                            Zaloguj się
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={styles.error}>
                        {this.state.error}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I'am quite confused how to fix that issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please be more specific. Can you try to reduce your code size to a minimum example that still fails with the same error?

Comment: I analyze this code for several hours and I really don't know where the problem is. If I delete all methods except render(), the problem is not showing up.

Comment: I also cannot see the problem at first hand, but I think it must be related to one of the <Text> tags. Could you try and comment out the <Text> components and their children and see if you still get the error?

Comment: @dentemm I removed this two <Text> tags inside <TouchableOpacity> and it doesn't have any impact.

Comment: Did you also try the <Text> tag for the error message?

Comment: I don't certainly what do You have on mind...

Comment: No I was thinking in the wrong direction... Now I am looking at your firebase code and am wondering if you are binding this correctly. You are binding your handlers in .then and .catch, but shouldn't you be calling them instead?

Comment: I don't think so - it's a typical promise mechanism...

Comment: Issue is happening even if I remove everything from render(), except a single and empty <View> tag...

Comment: where is this LoginForm being used?I do not see any export default here too

Comment: just below my styles object, of course it is

Comment: Does anybody know what that error means at all? All listed keys belong to ReactNode object. That IS a ReactNode, why it can't be rendered?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

Remove the firebase import statement from App.js:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

On Firebase initialization create a constant:

```
initializeFirebase() {
  const firebase = require("firebase");

  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
  ...
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  //inicializando o firestore
  const firestore = require("firebase/firestore");
  db = firebase.firestore();
  db.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
}

componentWillMount() {
  this.initializeFirebase();
...
}
```

To me this workaround works very well!

Comment: Thank You very much for help, it works! In fact removing firebase import statement from App.js didn't work, but it finally boots up when I remove this import from my component (LoginForm.js) and create this firebase variable inside my onButtonPress() method.

Comment: Thanks @Clebertom

Comment: This works for me, but don't miss @GrokSrc's solution below which explains how to still use `import` -> `import firebase from '@firebase/app'` and `import '@firebase/auth'`

Comment: @Celebertom, how can I use this solution in my config.js file, it is only js file and not a react-component? Config.js doesn't has react setup, so, How to use componentWillMount()? link is https://github.com/ganesh-deshmukh/exchange-o-gram/blob/master/app/config/config.js

Answer (score 41):

I had this problem today. I ran a diff on the source code between 5.0.3 and 5.0.4 and found that the exports have changed. I also found that if I change the import statement to the following that it works with the latest version (5.3.0):

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app'
import '@firebase/auth'
```

Doing it this way will allow you to avoid the `require` in the middle of your code, which is preferred imho.

Comment: This method gives me the error:

" _firebase.default.database is not a function: (In '_firebase.default.database()', '_firebase.default.database' is undefined)".  Okay, I fixed it.  I will post as a separate comment.

Comment: For this to work, you'll need to import all the parts for Firebase that you're using.  I wasn't using Auth, but was using Storage and Database.  So I had to add: import "@firebase/storage";
import "@firebase/database";

Comment: Super stoked that I didn't have to downgrade to get this to work, thanks much 

Comment: Worked for me. Remember to update the other files where you import firebase (not just App.js)

Answer (score 15):

It's an issue with firebase version 5.0.6 whereas downgrading to a version will resolve this issue.for example  try this

`$ npm install --save firebase@5.0.4`

If version 5.0.4 is also not working for you than try version 4.9.1 as this is what i am using and it resolved this issue for me

`$npm install --save firebase@4.9.1`

Comment: This worked for me. I started to use version 4.9.1 and problem went away.

Answer (score 7):

try to change the import statement to this:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me!

```
$npm install --save firebase@4.9.1
```

In firebase docs, they say:

**Fixed an issue where ES6 wildcard imports were breaking Closure Compiler**

LINK >> https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i solved it by removing the import statement of firebase:

```
import firebase from 'firebase'
```

and replace it by creating a global `const` inside my component that will be initialized once the component complete mounting :

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.firebase = require('firebase');
}
```

then you can use all firebase methods by using `this.firebase` ... 
example:

```
this.firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
   //Some Code
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 "dependencies": {
"firebase": "^5.5.9",
"react": "16.6.1",
"react-native": "0.57.7",
"react-native-material-kit": "^0.5.1",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0"
```

},
with above dependencies, I managed to solve this issue by doing following

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes with firebase version 5.0.6. Try downgrading firebase version by running this command.

```
$ npm install --save firebase@5.0.4
```

After this if issue still exist try downgrading firebase plugin to version 4.9.1

```
$npm install --save firebase@4.9.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back to firebase version 5.0.3 also resolves the issue.

Comment: Being stuck to an old version is bad, very bad.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't downgrade I just had to add

```
import "@firebase/database";
```

What it means is that you import each firebase component you want to use...(just hope this is right)

but it worked so well for me