# objects are not valid as react child (react-native)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to initialize firebase in my react native project.

[This is the error I am facing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRNmB.png)

code for `App.js` where I am initialising it is

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import firebase from 'firebase';

class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount () {
    const config = {
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "",
      databaseURL: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: ""
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
      <View>
        <Text>Hello! </Text>
      </View>
    </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I even face the same error when I only include `import firebase from 'firebase';` and don't initialize the `config`

Comment: This looks like the same error, so I'm linking them just in case: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/908#issuecomment-395117364

Comment: Had the same problem, cleberton response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555275/react-native-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-with-keys#_=_) fixed it for me.

Comment: Had the same issue, cleberton response [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555275/react-native-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-with-keys#_=_) fixed it for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The exports changed at version 5.0.4 and later. Now you need to do it like this:

`import firebase from '@firebase/app'`

If you're using eslint you'll probably get a complaint that it should be listed in the project dependencies, but you can ignore that.

You'll probably also want to use the actual features of firebase rather than just the core import. For example, to use the authentication module you'd add the following:

`import '@firebase/auth'`

Comment: for realtime-database is import '@firebase/database'?

Comment: Still don't understand why this can result on the reported error, but it worked for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing on constructor instead of componentWillMount

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import firebase from 'firebase';

class App extends Component {

 constructor(props){
    super(props)
    const config = {
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "",
      databaseURL: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: ""
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
      <View>
        <Text>Hello! </Text>
      </View>
    </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Didn't work! And I repeat the error is mainly due to `import firebase from 'firebase';` I need to important it successfully. I have installed firebase using `npm install firebase --save` in the root directory of project.