# react-native error after import firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native-firebase

I have installed `firebase` package in my project using cmd

```
npm install --save firebase
```

When I import firebase to my react-native project `import firebase from 'firebase'` I'm getting this error. What could be the problem?
[image]

Comment: You didn’t provide any error...

Comment: See https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/908 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50555275/react-native-objects-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child-found-object-with-keys

Comment: Also you could optionally try  import * as firebase from 'firebase'

Comment: Because of firebase version.
Just change firebase version 4.10.0 to 4.13.0 working well 
Your change firebase Version direct by go to edit it in your package.json than “run install”
Change your import statement to 
import * as firebase from ‘firebase’;

Comment: Any solutiuon for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow this pattern the error will be resolved the issue is due to upgradation in `Firebase` repo:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
// import firebase from 'firebase';
import firebase from '@firebase/app'
import { Header } from './Components/Common';
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into Same issue i solved it by installing *babel polyfill*

```
npm i --save-dev babel-polyfill
```

then in my **index.js**:

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
```

Answer (score 0):

thats because of the recent version of firebase you can roll back to version 4 or you can import like

import firebase from '@firebase/app'; 
any of the above two approaches will solve your problem